# Accessing constructor with value initialization?

Tags: c++

So according to [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), the notations `A()` and `new A()` cause value initialization. It is my understanding that both notations should then transform into default-initialization

> for if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a
>   user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is
>   default-initialized;

from which they should cause the same behavior. Then, why this:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image();
    virtual ~Image();

protected:
    std::string _filePath;

protected:
    // noncopyable
    Image(const Image& rImg);
    Image& operator=(const Image&);
    bool initWithImageFileThreadSafe(const std::string& fullpath);

};

int main()
{
    auto a = new Image(); //Works
    auto aa = Image(); //Error: inaccessible constructor
}
```

Comment: Compile as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fded40a9ad8f1df). Second line in `main` requires C++17 for *"guarantied elision"*.

Comment: Clean compile: live https://godbolt.org/z/OdMGDQ  Perhaps add details of your tool-chain and switches.

Comment: Fails with C++14 live: https://godbolt.org/z/wsVmt7  But your comments apprear to be swapped.

Comment: Ah, C++17's guaranteed copy elision comes into play here.

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
auto a = new Image(); //Works
```

You create an `Image` dynamically and `a` is initialized with a pointer to it.  This is fine as it is direct initialization of the `Image`.

When you do

```
auto aa = Image(); //Error: inaccessible constructor
```

Pre C++17, you invoke copy initialization which uses a value initialized temporary `Image` as the value to initialize `aa`.  Since your copy constructor is marked `protected` this isn't actually allowed to happen and you get a compiler error.  Even though this copy can be elided, you still need an accessible copy/move constructor.

Post C++17 no temporary is actually generated here and the compiler essentially transforms the code to `Image aa{};` so that the copy is elided and there is no need for an accessible copy/move constructor.